# How Can I Link the Child of a Child to the Primary Entity when doing a Deep Insert into Microsoft Dynamics

Tags: deep-linking, microsoft-dynamics

I have a situation where I need to link an sub entity (directdebit) to the primary entity (customeraccount) while doing a deep insert. The deep insert creates the following entities:

customerAccount -> bankAccount -> directdebit

The directDebit entity needs a reference to the customerAccount entity.

It looks like the deep insert only creates references between parent and child out of the box, i.e it creates a refence between customerAccount and bankAccount, or bankAccount and directdebit.

Is there some way of referencing the customerAccount entity (which is being created in the same deep insert) and getting its id so that I can insert into the directDebit entity?

My payload for the deep insert looks similar to this:

```
{
    "customername": "Jo Bolggs",
    "bankaccounts":[
        {
            "bankaccountname":"Current Account",
            "banksortcode": "11-22-33",
            "bankaccountnumber": "87654321",
            "DirectDebits":[
                {
                    "customerid": "?????????????",
                    "ddistatus": 125500000,
                    "suppressionstatus": true,
                    "validfrom": "2023-08-31T11:10:00.3877362+01:00"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```